# Using dup2 from file to another file

Tags: c, linux, shell, dup2

I'm trying to execute the command sort < in.txt > out.txt, so I am using dup2.
This is my code:

```
    int fdin = open("in.txt",O_RDWR);
    int fdout = open("out.txt",O_RDWR);

    dup2(fdin,fdout);
    //close(fdin);
    //close(fdout);
    //execvp...
```

How exactly does dup2 work? I can't get it...
Thank you!

Comment: [Read the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html)?

Comment: Yes my friend that's why I am posting here because I find it hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use it closes `fdout` again, removing its connection to `fdout`, and then connects it to the `fdin`. So if `fdin` and `fdout` are, maybe, 4 and 5, both 4 and 5 now point to `in.txt`.

Rather than that, you should do something like

```
dup2(fdin, 0) // now 0 will point to the same as fdin
dup2(fdout, 1) // now 1 will point to the same as fdout
close(fdin); // as we don't need these any longer - if they are not 0 or 1! That should be checked.
close(fdout);
execvp(...);
```

There are some other pitfalls to be taken care for, however. For example, you should `fork()` before this one if you want your process to go on what it does.

Why this comment at `close()` above? Well, when your process hasn't fd 0 and/or 1 open (what would be unusual, but not impossible), `fdin` might be 0 or 1 and `fdout` might be 1. These situations you have to cope with.

An even better way would be

```
if (fdin > 0) {
    dup2(fdin, 0); // now 0 will point to the same as fdin
    close(fdin);
}
if (fdout > 1) { // cannot be 0!
    dup2(fdout, 1) // now 1 will point to the same as fdout
    close(fdout);
}
execvp(...);
```

Comment: I am using what you recommended but still not working. I put the close() in comments because I don't really knew when to close them.
I am using fork before by the way. What happens even with your code is that the program outputs the sorted contents of the in.txt on the screen